# Change AWS Elastic beanstalk default URL for healthcheck to subdomain

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I've deployed a laravel application to AWS Elastibeanstalk via code pipeline. I've added linked by the website to a subdomain rather than an EBS-provided domain. However, my app is working totally fine but the status of the health is severe with the following error:

```
Target.FailedHealthChecks
```

I'm thinking that EBS is using its own domain for checking the website's health status and is failing as the App is not responding to HTTP protocol  My app has the code to always listen to HTTPS requests and not HTTP. I've configured the load balancer's default protocol to HTTPS and added a URL that is returning 200 response for the status checks but still, the health is showing as severe. How can I change the domain of EBS to check for health on that domain rather than using its own created one?

Comment: I believe you can change the uri for the health check, but it must be on port 80. I'd set up a route that responds over http just to eliminate that from your investigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By going to AWS EBS -> Configurations->Load balancer, I was able to change the value of default in **Processes** by modifying the port to 443 with HTTPS protocol and adding the path to the URL, the status check was transferred to checking on the provided route with the HTTPS request. The load balancer will always check the default domain for the status health check.